# application gets while coming to back to view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Here is the viewWillAppear function.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

    //creating object of childDataDB to fetch the data from childData table
    ChildDataDB *objectChildDataDB = [[ChildDataDB alloc] autorelease];
    [objectChildDataDB connectToDatabase ];
    [objectChildDataDB checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [objectChildDataDB readChildDataTable];

    //array fetches the data from database with the help of ChildRecordDB class

    self.fetchChildrenArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    self.fetchChildrenArray = [objectChildDataDB returnNameMutableArray];
}
```

My problem is when first time view gets loaded it works fine. But after navigating to some other view and coming back it gets crashed.

Could anyone please solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the error message from the crash?

Comment: This may be a typo but `ChildDataDB *objectChildDataDB = [[ChildDataDB alloc] autorelease];` is incorrect as there's no `init`.

Comment: The first line of the method should be `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in this method is strange. Creating database's from a viewWillAppear: lifecycle method doesn't seem right.

Also....

```
ChildDataDB *objectChildDataDB = [[ChildDataDB alloc] autorelease];
```

should probably read

```
ChildDataDB *objectChildDataDB = [[[ChildDataDB alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Give a crash report and it may provide more info for someone to help you.